# Firebase Analytics Event properties are not shown, but do appear in DebugView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have added Firebase Analytics events to my android app, and when I tested it with DebugView, I could clearly see the events and all their properties.

However, after launching the app, I can only see the events themselves, and the properties are missing.

I'm using :

```
val props = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
props["test key"] = "test value"

Firebase.analytics.logEvent("action_test", props.toBundle())
```

As stated above, it works perfectly fine when I test it using the DebugView in Firebase console.

But when I go to Events sections, and click on some event, and then go to `add filter`, I cannot see the event properties.
The only thing I see is in that page, some statistics like the total number of events, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase under "Analytics" click on "Events". Then click on the specific event you want to see the parameters of.

In your example the event name is "action_test", the parameter name is "test_key", the parameter values are the values of the map.

Now click on "action_test" in Events. It will open a detailed view for the event. Some cards will have as the title the name of the parameter.

It will take some time before the events are shown. Can be up to a couple of hours.

Comment: This is my page of an event with should have parameters : https://ibb.co/NW7Fbfc
But I still don't see the parameters.
Am I missing something?

Comment: @BVtp Looks like this. https://i.imgur.com/JSrQHew.png

No need to do anything. Will be show automatically.
It will take a couple of hourse before the parameters are shown. Unlike in DebugView where they are near real time.

Comment: this is strange, all I see are the following : Events in the last 30 minutes, Event location, Event demographics, Events per session. Those events were fired more than 2 hours ago, some were from a few days ago. But I don't see the properties like you do in the screenshot that you attached.

Comment: I also have the same problem. I tried to read here https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7397304?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489 how to visualize event parameters but the button it says to press (edit parameter reporting) simply is not present on my dashboard. It's possible it might be related to the warning on the top that says "This feature is being replaced by event-scoped custom dimensions and metrics." it's incredible they are not more clear with such a major changing. But that's just an hypothesis. Hope there are other explanation